# how to remove the point from the address

Tags: apache, .htaccess

please help to solve the problem.

have a website. it's his .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Сначала внешний редирект, который поправит "." и "www" 
  # если в этом есть необходимость
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.avroraprint.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

  # И уже на запросе с поправленным хостом начинает работать
  # перенаправление от CMS
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]  
</IfModule>
```

the problem is that the following addresses:

```
www.avroraprint.ru./about/guest-reviews/ 
www.avroraprint.ru. 
www.avroraprint.ru..
```

but the point after "ru" should not be. ie addresses should only be allowed as follows:

```
www.avroraprint.ru/about/guest-reviews/ 
www.avroraprint.ru 
www.avroraprint.ru
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `301` rules seems to be faulty and will cause infinite redirection loop.

Change that rule to this:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.avroraprint.ru/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```